# Call Jquery base function in client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, function, events

I want call a simple function On client side event of one of my controls asp.net;

but i'm unsuccessfully to do this.

I'm new to jquery ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UploadStart() {
        var FileName = $('#ctl00_MainPlaceHolder_AsyncFileUpload_ctl00').attr('value');
        $('#txtLink').attr('value', FileName);
        $('#<%=BtnUpload.ClientID %>').css('display', 'none');
    }

</script>
```

aspx :

```
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtLink" style="width:200px;" class="EngTextBox" />
        </td>
        <td id="UploadControls" style="width:215px; text-align:center;">
            <input type="button" id="BtnBrowseFile" class="BtnBack" value="انتخاب فایل" />
            <asp:Button Text="آپلود" ID="BtnUpload" CssClass="BtnBack" runat="server" OnClick="BtnUpload_Click" />
            <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload" runat="server" OnUploadedComplete="Upload_Completed" OnClientUploadStarted="UploadStart();" />
            </td>
    </tr>
```

OnClientUploadStarted event must be do some jquery ticks ...

Answer (score 0):

i solve it,

'();' is my problem ! :D

call :

OnClientUploadStarted="UploadStart"

but, why ?!!!